# How to specify the total number of image results for .media_search method from Instagram-ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, instagram

I want to return 18 photos from the .media_search method provided by the Instagram-ruby gem.  The source codes says to pass in an options hash with key :count => some_integer
The problem is that the gem returns what appears to be a random response number when I do add the options hash.  Sometimes it will return 8 other times 4 etc.

What am I missing???
Thanks.

Here's my sample file I am working with

```
    require 'instagram'
    require 'faraday'

    Instagram.configure do |config|
      config.client_id     = "CLIENT_ID"
      config.client_secret = "CLIENT_SECRET"
    end

    result = Instagram.media_search("40.7143528", "-74.00597309999999", {:count => 18})
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the [media_search](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/blob/master/lib/instagram/client/media.rb#L57) method within the instagram-ruby-gem does accept an options hash, the **count** parameter is not an allowed parameter for this particular endpoint as can be seen within Instagram's API documentation [here](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_search)